# cakephp save many arrays with saveMany

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

with these sample two arrays:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'admission_no' => '1003',
    'exam_id' => '1',
    'subject_code' => (int) 101,
    'score' => '61'
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'admission_no' => '1003',
    'exam_id' => '1',
    'subject_code' => (int) 102,
    'score' => '85'
)
```

)

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'admission_no' => '1005',
    'exam_id' => '1',
    'subject_code' => (int) 101,
    'score' => '63'
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'admission_no' => '1005',
    'exam_id' => '1',
    'subject_code' => (int) 102,
    'score' => '14'
)
```

)

i have already managed to put them in the format required by saveMany(). i have tried with foreach loop but only manages to save the first array. it may be simple but for some reason my loop doesnt work as expected

also..it worth mentioning that the above arrays are a result of some manipulation of a csv file. the code i used to get them are here:

```
public function combineElements ($arr) {
    $columns = array('admission_no','exam_id','subject_code','score');
    $cust = array_combine($columns,$arr);
    return $cust;
    //debug($cust);
}

public function resultsUpload () {
    $modelClass = $this->modelClass;

    //populate the $data variable using CsvComponent
    $data = $this->Csv->import(($this->request->data[$modelClass]['result']['tmp_name']));
    //get the exam category passed from the $_POST variable
    $exam_cat = $this->request->data[$modelClass]['exam_id'];
    //debug($data);

    //$columns = array('admission_no','exam_id','subject_code','score');
    //manipulate $data array to get values as desired
    foreach ($data as $value) {
         //remove the first element of $value and retain the indexes to retrieve subjects and scores
         $new_sliced = array_slice($value, 1,(sizeof($value) - 1),true);
        $subject = array_keys($new_sliced);
        $scores = array_values($new_sliced);
        $number = array_shift($value);
         $result_data = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($subject); $i++) {
        $result_data[] = $number;
        $result_data[] = $exam_cat;
        $result_data[] = $subject[$i];
        $result_data[] = $scores[$i];
        }
        //debug($result_data);
       $customized = array_chunk($result_data,4);
      //debug($customized);
      $data_set = array_map(array($this, 'combineElements'),$customized);
      debug($data_set);
       $this->$modelClass->create();

     if($this->$modelClass->saveMany($k, array(
        'validate' => false, 'atomic' => true
      ))){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Results uploaded successfully'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
      }else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Could not upload results.Check for errors then try again'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'resultsUpload'));
      }
    }
    }
    $exams = $this->ExamsScore->Exam->find('list',array('fields' => array('exam_type')));
     $this->set('modelClass',$modelClass);
     $this->set('exams',$exams);
     $this->render('../Common/upload');
    // debug($exams);
}
```

the above arrays are the results of debug($data_set)

Answer (score 0):

Try with SaveAll..

```
 if($this->$modelClass->saveAll($data, array(
    'validate' => false, 'atomic' => true
  ))){}
```

Also one thing what is $k stands for in saveMany function.

Edit..

Make sure in saveMany or saveAll, pass your array like:

```
array(
    0 => array(
            'MyModel' => array(
                'admission_no' => '1005',
                'exam_id' => '1',
                'subject_code' => (int) 101,
                'score' => '63'
            )
        ),
    1 => array(
        'MyModal' => array(
            'admission_no' => '1005',
            'exam_id' => '1',
            'subject_code' => (int) 102,
            'score' => '14'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: $k should be $data_set..i was using it to view what i was passing to the saveMany.it has no effect since i replaced it before running the code

Comment: i've edit the code. make sure about the array structure. Thanks..!